# How does firebase distinguish between websites for firebase analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I know that using firebase in a web app requires putting some public config keys in the front end code and that its safe to do so. But I am confused about how firebase would prevent malicious people from just copying those config keys and pasting them in their own sites and initializing the firebase analytics sdk there to try to spoil my analytics data.

In firebase auth, we also give some whitelisted domains and authentication services are only allowed on those domains by firebase. So even if we try to access those auth services from another domain, firebase won't allow it.

So how will firebase differentiate in case of analytics? If the same config keys are put in webpages on two sites abc.com and xyz.com and abc.com is my actual site whose traffic is supposed to be tracked, how will firebase know and discard data from the bad website xyz.com if the person who created xyz just copied my config from my front end code and initialized firebase.analytics() on their site to spoil my analytics?